# Center text vertically centered within a div

Tags: css

I want to center text vertically aligned without using the box property because It does not work in IE9 so I have read it. I have only IE 10 here...

http://jsfiddle.net/J8rL7/6/

I have also tried display:table-cell and vertical-align:middle but this destroyed the whole layout.

Are there any vertical align tricks for my scenario which support IE9+, Chrome/Firefox (latest).

```
<div id="wrapper" style="margin:auto;background-color:yellow;height:100%;">
    <div style="width:50px;height:100%;">
        <div class="fluid-column" style="height:80%;background-color:green;">
            <div style="display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-pack:center;-webkit-box-align:center;background-color:#ff99cc;height:25%;">1</div>
            <div style="display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-pack:center;-webkit-box-align:center;background-color:#ff33cc;height:50%;">2</div>
            <div style="display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-pack:center;-webkit-box-align:center;background-color:#ff66cc;height:25%;">3</div>
        </div>   
        <div class="fix-column" style="height:20%;background-color:violet">
            <div style="display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-pack:center;-webkit-box-align:center;background-color:orange;height:50%;">Total</div>
            <div style="display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-pack:center;-webkit-box-align:center;background-color:blue;height:50%;">Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using div there might be no direct way to align text in center. Either replace ur divs with table or use padding-top: 50% for divs with text values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's update this and go old ways, so older IEs should come in the run too:
Let's use specifitie of inline-boxes and use one inline-level empty element to secure vertical-align.
DEMO to test : http://jsfiddle.net/D9gnP/6/ - http://jsfiddle.net/D9gnP/6/show.

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    text-align:center;
    /* text-indent:-0.5em; to swallow word spacing , should be right value */
}
div span {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:0;/* no need to have a width, it's got be invisible */
    margin:0 -5px;/* this will reduce effect of word spacing to none, it can be a little oversized */
}
```

<s>If you want to use table-cell, you need to start from the main container drawing the column. and end up with table-cells to use the vertical-align rule.

I added an extra span to get to it :</s>

http://jsfiddle.net/D9gnP/

```
.fluid-column,
.fix-column{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}
.fluid-column > div,
.fix-column > div{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.fluid-column > div > span,
.fix-column > div> span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: "...If you want to use table-cell..." I want to use what fits best into my scenario working for IE9+, FF and Chrome latest and be valid html5 and css. If there is nothing "better" than table-cell, than this might be a solution.

Comment: Just tested it and it failed in IE10. The layout is broken.

Comment: oki , thanks for feed back. it actually fails in chrome when you right open the fiddle, resize window and it's fine. Can you check this link (full pge) http://jsfiddle.net/D9gnP/show/ (it just reminds me why I disliked jsfddle/codepen)

Comment: yes for chrome the fiddle seems ok. But it does not work in ANY version of Internet Explorer :/ only when I activate the quirks mode... but thats no option.

Comment: Okay, so i change my mind, and i propose the old way for that. it should work, height is then suppose to be inherited without being swap from some table-family display :)

Comment: roughly said it looks ok in IE all version BUT when I look more close to it something is wrong now with the horizontal centering of the text. Put a ruler vertically along the numbers and you see they are shifted a bit. Above all number 1 and 2 but not 3. Why is that?

Comment: Cause the text itself stands on baseline, if its wrap into an inline-box, then you can set its vertical-align to middle too. You may use a <b>, <s> or whatever short and unused inline-block-level tag instead of span and wrap text in a span to get it working. Pixel perfect is a mythe though, and waste of time , it's not print ;)

Comment: Well centered is centered... 3 pixel less is not centered. Your solution looks now like the one from Perro Azul. What was so bad about his suggestion? What you think?

Comment: Well I told how to fixe those 3 pixels, move the text from it's baseline to middle wrapping it into a tag on wich you can apply any rules you like :). There is no magic in CSS. (see my comment @Perro Azul proposal) By the way do not hesitate to correct my english if i use it wrong. it seems clear to me , but .. is it

Comment: I just realized wich 3 pixels you are talking about :) There where no space in between span and '3' . This extra element should have a width of 0 not disturb text-align : center :) (pseudo option includes IE8 + or IE9 + if you write ::before

Comment: sorry but I can not follow you. And it feels odd to fumble around with the width: 0 -4px; settings to get the text centered horizontally correctly what worked actually before your changes...

Comment: Don't mind it if you think it doesn't interact with text-centering :) .This negative margin is to reduce its width and word-spacing to none. Actually the right css should be: width:0; and tex-indent:-0.5em;instead of negative margin. word-spacing between element and text do not diseapear, but is swallowed. Negative margin can over sized, it causes no problem, but text-indent can pull/push too far text from a browser to another. Why my choice for negative margin :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D9gnP/24/ here a version with text-indent: You notice well its effect on the last cells, where words are bigger. Do not use negative margin or text-indent and see it's not perfectly centered. ... I hope that you follow me now :) and see what i'm talking about. (this one no correction from effects of span in HTML  http://jsfiddle.net/D9gnP/20/ )

Comment: See same effects if using pseudo element || plain : http://jsfiddle.net/D9gnP/25/  ||  negative margin : http://jsfiddle.net/D9gnP/26/ || negative text-indent:  http://jsfiddle.net/D9gnP/27/

Comment: with -0,1em it looks best centered lol. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `"text-align: center;"` in div tag.
It is done, check below link..
http://jsfiddle.net/J8rL7/15/

Answer (score 0):

I've used this trick before for vertical alignment:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="center">vertically centered content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { white-space:nowrap; height:200px; }
#container:before { content:""; display:inline-block; width:0; height:100%; vertical-align:middle; }
.center { display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; white-space:normal; }
```

This creates a pseudo-element before the element with `class="center"` and uses `inline-block` so the `vertical-align` style takes effect.

Here's a jsfiddle so you can check if it works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Etzpj/

I think that in your case you would need to wrap the text on each cell with another element for this trick to work.

Edit: here i used this trick in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J8rL7/25/

Comment: this trick, if you use an extra inline element in HTML (with rules for the pseudo), it make IE5 to 7 to  understand it . Problem, (not here), height must be set or known on parent

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/J8rL7/24/

If you look at http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ and the heading: Absolute Positioning and Stretching

It requires adding a span around each text field, and a couple of classes

```
.vert {
  position: relative;  
}

.span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;   

}
```

Comment: hell... you are showing me MY code snippet with my vertical box settings and add your flavour... to it. Where is the proove that yours work and not mine...??